# Бот постоянно должен проверять баланс и уведомлять, если есть изменения

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Как сделать, чтобы бот без команды, просто в лайв режиме проверял данные, в моём случае баланс на блокчейне, и если есть изменения отсылал мне в лс.
Саму проверку баланса и отправку данных в лс я уже сделал, но у меня это всё происходит при вводе команды.
Вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы бот без тригера сам проверял этот баланс.

Comment: функцию проверки баланса запихнуть в aioschedule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
chat_ids = []

# команда, по которой бот начинает рассылать уведомления пользователю
# если нужно рассылать всем, то это все нужно делать в обработчике команды start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start-update-balance-notifications'])
async def schedule_update_balance(message):
    chat_ids.append(message.chat.id)
    
    # после перезагрузки бота придется заново давать команду 
    # stat-update-balance-notifications
    # если нужно, чтоб после перезапуска бот продолжал рассылать уведомления
    # нужно в этом месте сохранять chat_ids в файл или БД
    # а при старте бота читать из файла или БД список в chat_ids

async def get_balance():
    # тут получаем баланс
    ...
    return balance

async def update_balance():
    new_balance = await get_balance()
    for chat_id in chat_ids:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, f"Баланс {new_balance}")

def repeat(coro, loop):
    asyncio.ensure_future(coro(), loop=loop)
    loop.call_later(DELAY, repeat, coro, loop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.call_later(DELAY, repeat, update_price, loop)
    executor.start_polling(dp, loop=loop)
```