# Aiogram. Executor. Методы и их параметры

Tags: python, aiogram

Пытаюсь разобраться в aiogram. Интересуют методы executor-а. В чём разница, принципы работы. А так же параметры, которые каждый из этих методов принимает. К примеру, что передаётся в loop, и т.д.

Проблема, лично для меня, в том, что сухой документации, при моём уровне знаний и опыта, недостаточно.
Может у кого-то есть источники, с подробными объяснениями.
Заранее спасибо!

Конкретно сейчас интересует реализации следующей задачи: есть асинхронная функция, по которой бот отправляет сообщение в групповой чат с инфой из БД. Сама функция работает. Если впихнуть эту функцию в on_startup с последующей передачей в соответствующий параметр, то бот кроме неё ничего не выполняет. Знаний на другие варианты решений - нет. Именно с этой реализацией и нужна помощь

```
async def report():
    time_now = time.localtime()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if time_now.tm_hour == 8 and time_now.tm_min == 0 and tm_sec == 0:
        # исполняемый код
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, #результат исполняемого кода)


async def on_startup(_):
    print('бот вышел в онлайн')
    await report


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

И, если не затруднит, в чём разница start_polling и start_webhook?

P.S. Можно конечно найти нужное и готовое решение на просторах интернета, но, всё таки хочется понимать, что делаешь.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA ок, добавил.

Comment: `бот кроме неё ничего не выполняет` - тут проблема не с функцией или ее конфигурацией. Что именно другое вы ожидаете от бота, чего он не делает? Нужен код именного того другого, потому что, только с тем кодом, что вы привели, он ничего кроме этого сообщения при старте делать не будет. `starting_polling` - это режим работы бота, когда он периодически делает запросы на телеграм сервер, чтоб узнать если ли новые сообщения. `start_webhook` - это режим, когда телеграм сервер делает запросы к боту по http (сам бот должен быть доступен из интернета) чтоб сообщить о новых сообщениях.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Бот не выполняет весь написанный код, т.е. не реагирует на команды, не входит в "машину состояний" и прочее. Без  def report() всё работает, вопросов нет. В функции def report() бесконечный цикл и нужно, чтобы она работала параллельно, а сейчас, судя по всему выполняется только она. И, вопрос по start_webhook, правильно понимаю, что при таком методе возможности у бота выше (количество обрабатываемых запросов от пользователя единовременно)? И можно ли start_webhook использовать без загрузки бота на сервер, с локального компьютера?

Comment: Добавил пример цикла.

Comment: Скажите, как по предыдущему тексту вопроса можно догадаться, что в report есть цикл? :) Это ж все существенно меняет. Вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1302045/218971 есть пример того, как можно делать регулярную задачу в фоне. webhook-и можно использовать с локального компа, нужно только обеспечить доступ к нему из интернета. у webhook преимущества в том, что задержка с уведомлениями потенциально ниже и нагрузка на серверы телеграма ниже, т.к. бот их не долбит постоянно. Количество обрабатываемых запросов зависит не от этого, а от реализации бота, сложности обработчика и т.д.

Comment: Еще большая проблема, что вы используете синхронный sleep в цикле асинхронной функции. Это в любом случае плохо, но в этом - это просто не отдает никогда управление основному циклу asyncio.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136834/discussion-between--and-roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт.

Для себя выбрал вот такой вариант решения

[Как реализовать параллельную работу телеграм-бота и бесконечного цикла с помощью aiogram? (Python)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1327856/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E)

Отдельное спасибо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218971/roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua за толчок к изучению asyncio и ссылки на рабочие варианты решений. Вообще, их достаточно много на этом ресурсе. Всё зависит от постановки самого вопроса.