# Как передать асинхронную функцию в multiprocces.Process Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, aiogram, async-await

Пишу ТГ бота на aiogram, python. Столкнулся с проблемой, мне нужно запустить отдельный процесс с помощью multiprocessing Procces(). Но как передать в аргумент target асинхронную функцию?
Это часть функции телеграмм бота

```
 elif #Нужное условие#:
    p = mp.Process(target=sc.main #файл импортирован как sc# , args=(user_data['query'], user_data['max_subs'], user_data['req_amount'],
                                         user_id, message, kb_client))
    p.start()
await state.finish()
```

Это сама функция

```
async def main(query, max_subs, req_amount, user_id, message, kb_client):
#Куча не нужных переменных#
file_d = f"handlers/Scraper/data/{user_id}_data.csv"

get_data(#куча не нужных аргументов#)


file = open(file_d, "rb")
await message.answer(file, reply_markup=kb_client)
os.remove(file_d)

multiprocessing.current_process().close()
```

Если что без `message.answer()` все отлично работает.
Возможно есть вариант запуска `message.answer()` без `await` чтобы не делать функцию асинхронной. Пожалуйста, любое решение, очень нужно!

Comment: Не уверен что помогу. Но есть вариант без multiprocessing Procces(). https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1417441/aiogram-executor-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b/1418333#1418333. Работа отдельной асинхронной функции. Мне помогло.

Comment: @Дмитрий Попробовал сделать в функции main();   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(send_file(file=file, message=message, kb_client=kb_client)), где send_file() - функция которая посылает файл (await message.answer()). Выдает ошибку - RuntimeError: this event loop is already running.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, но оно не совсем красивое. Сделал отдельную функцию которая будет отправлять результат при нажатии на кнопку.
Так же она будет проверять выполняется ли еще запрос с помощью

```
for proc in proc_l:
    if proc.name == message.from_user.id:
    await message.answer("Ваш запрос еще выполняется")
```