# Как отправить сообщение без команды пользователя в aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot

Хочу написать телеграм бот на aiogram.
Для ответа на команду используется:

```python
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message:  types.Message):
    await message.answer("Привет")

@dp.message_handler(commands=["stop"])
async def stop(message:  types.Message):
    await message.answer("Пока")
```

Для реакции на простое сообщение:

```python
# пример echo-bot
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message:  types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)
```

Если пользователь отправляет медиа:

```python
@dp.message_handler(content_type=["photo"])
async def photo(message:  types.Message):
    await message.answer("Вы отправили фото")

@dp.message_handler(content_type=["video"])
async def video(message:  types.Message):
    await message.answer("Вы отправили видео")
```

Вопрос: есть ли метод, который отправляет сообщение пользователя, без сообщения от него самого. Например, по расписанию или в определенное время?

Comment: Сообщение, без сообщения?

Comment: Да. Суть в том, что выше описанные методы срабатывают, исходя от содержимого отправленного пользователем сообщения. Хочу понять, как отправить в чат сообщение, не получая его от пользователя.

P.S. Заметил, что некоторые боты отправляют рекламу, даже если я ему ничего не пишу. Как сделать такое же?

Comment: Для начала, важна очередь расположения хендлеров. Если "пустой" будет в начале, то перехватит все сообщения. По поводу Вашего вопроса, вот один из вариантов решения https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1417441/aiogram-executor-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b. Запуск кода по времени.

Comment: Спасибо большое. То, что искал.